# Liferay Spanish Language character displaying as junk character

Tags: liferay-7

I am using liferay 7.2 my application.
   I have custom portlet where 3 dropdown are there.
   I have used spanish language for labels which is working but for some labels it is displaying entity.First dropdown working with entity but other are not working.

I have used https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm to replace special character.

```
 Ex.
  Language.properties
    select-category = Select Category
    select-sub-category = Select Sub-Category
  Language_es.properties
    //This is displaying junk character 
     select-category=selecciona una categoría
     select-sub-category=Seleccionar subcategoría

    //I have replace above with entity but it is displying same as it is written.
    select-category=Seleccionar subcategor&iacute;a
    select-sub-category=Seleccionar Sub-Categor&iacute;a
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "junk character"? 

Double check everything is encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: Where I need to do this?

Comment: You have to check all your *.properties files are encoded in UTF-8

If you are using Windows and Eclipse, it is very likely that all files are created with "Cp1252" codification